# Unrecognisable script in the Content window

Tags: charles-proxy

Having trouble to read the contents from the Content window in the sequence mode , I see unrecognisable Script 
I am using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5 
Steps followed

Enter into the Charles ->use the app for which I am testing -> Select the request for which I need to see the detailed content-> go to sequence mode -> enter into the content window and observe the content

[image]

Comment: I would highly recommend you to reformat your question so it becomes more visually readable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to monitor HTTPS requests? If so, please notice that you will need to do some extra configuration to the application (such as a browser) you are trying to monitor.

See the Charles Proxy documentation [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/).